# Badge never cleared

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

I'm using urban air ship component for titanium appcelerator.

iOS sdk ios6.1
Titanium SDK 3.1.1GA

When i send a notification by urban air ship, i receive the message and the notification ..that's ok ! and the application badge is set to the number i've sent ..it's cool !

But when i start my application the badge never come back to 0... i always have 1 notification set for the badge.

I've tried to clear all notifications with :

```
Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(null);
Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge("0");
Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge("-1");

Titanium.UI.iPhone.badge = "0";
Titanium.UI.iPhone.badge = "-1";
Titanium.UI.iPhone.badge = null;

Ti.App.iOS.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
```

Nothing can clear the badge... it's always set to 1.

Anyone can help ?
Is there a property that i have to set 0 or to null ??

Thx !

Comment: My first guess is that the code be called thus: `Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(0);` since it want's a number not a string. Also `Ti.App.iOS.cancelAllLocalNotifications();` will only work for local not for push notifications.

Comment: gonna try with number...
maybe my mistake with the doc :

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.8.0.1/Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge-method.html

Comment: The documentation you linked to is out of date, it's for 1.8.* try: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone

Comment: Tried with number, but same result..the badge come again and again with 1.

I've sent a new test notification (urbanairship) with a badge value to 20.. when i receive the notification the badge change for the good value 20
I open the application.. and close it.. and the badge come back to 1 .. it's amazing !!

Comment: Check if you are using `Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge()` in some other place, probably some background process. Also try removing application from device.

Answer (score 1):

you can reset the notification badge by placing this line where you want in your project

```
Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge=0;
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried this ?

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


 Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(0);
 Ti.App.iOS.cancelAllLocalNotifications();

 }
```